# Laravel - Parse error in /laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I made loads of changes within my code and unfortunately kind of lost track what were the last one.. but I guess one of them created this weird problem. 
When I'm trying to run `php artisan serve`, I get this error -

```
Parse error: parse error in /Users/Guest/admanager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 500
```

And the function that returns the error in helpers.php looks like this -

```
function factory()
{
    $factory = app(EloquentFactory::class);

    $arguments = func_get_args();

    if (isset($arguments[1]) && is_string($arguments[1])) {
        return $factory->of($arguments[0], $arguments[1])->times($arguments[2] ? null); // specifically, this is line 500
    } elseif (isset($arguments[1])) {
        return $factory->of($arguments[0])->times($arguments[1]);
    }

    return $factory->of($arguments[0]);
}
```

Comment: What is your php version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I just uninstalled xampp and it downgraded my locally running php version, hence the artisan serve didn't know how to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

Please change as per below code,

$arguments[2] ? null TO  $arguments[2] ?? null

Comment: yes.. i think it is a matter of my built-in mac's php version. will try to upgrade now and i'll update on this.